# Redirecting Subdir to HTTPS

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a site, mydomain.com/secure which I only want to be accessible via HTTPs. This is mapped as a virtual directory like this:

```
-wwwroot
--secure (Virtual directory, bound on port 443 only) - https://mydomain.com:443/secure
--externalApp (Mapped as a different site on port 80) - http://mydomain.com/
```

Currently requests to mydomain.com/secure are served, but I want to force them to redirect to HTTPs. Despite trying with rewrite rules I can't get this to work properly. Is it possible or just not doable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(example|secure|test) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You can add any directory you want in the example|secure|test area.

[Example with comments.](http://sslcertificatewiki.com/doku.php/redirect_drupal_or_ubercart_to_a_ssl_connection_with_htaccess)